# xml to excel Asp.net MVC. Parser Error. Encountered end tag "ss:Row" with no matching start tag

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, export-to-excel

I'm trying to export to Excel by using xml template. each time i run this its giving me a parser error at the code line "`</ss:Row>`", the one in the foreach loop, if i'm commenting out  the foreach loop it works fine. Is anybody know if some settings should be added to this?

```
@model PBD_DealerConsole.Models.ExportData
@{
Layout = null;
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
//Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Model.FileName);
//Content-Disposition is defined in RFC-2183
var rows = Model.DetailsGrid.Count + 1;
}
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<ss:Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <ss:Worksheet ss:Name="Datagrid">
<ss:Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="17" ss:ExpandedRowCount="@rows" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="20">
  <ss:Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
    <ss:Cell ecProperty="">
      <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Part #</Data>
    </ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ecProperty="">
      <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Description</Data>
    </ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ecProperty="">
      <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Cost</Data>
    </ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ecProperty="">
      <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Core</Data>
    </ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ecProperty="">
      <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Source</Data>
    </ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ecProperty="">
      <ss:Data ss:Type="String">12 Mo Sales</Data>
    </ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ecProperty="">
      <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Mo No Sale</Data>
    </ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ecProperty="">
      <ss:Data ss:Type="String">QOH</Data>
    </ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ecProperty="">
      <ss:Data ss:Type="String">QOO</Data>
    </ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ecProperty="">
      <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Qty Avail</Data>
    </ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ecProperty="">
      <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Qty Req</Data>
    </ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ecProperty="">
      <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Avg Mo Supply</Data>
    </ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ecProperty="">
      <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Stocking Status</Data>
    </ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ecProperty="">
      <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Bin</Data>
    </ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ecProperty="">
      <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Last Sale Date</Data>
    </ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ecProperty="">
      <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Last Received Date</Data>
    </ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ecProperty="">
      <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Pkg of</Data>
    </ss:Cell>
  </ss:Row>
  @foreach (var row in Model.DetailsGrid)
  {
    <ss:Row>
        <ss:Cell>
            <ss:Data ss:type="String">@row.PartNumber</Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
            <ss:Data ss:type="String">@row.Description</Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
            <ss:Data ss:type="String">@row.Cost</Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
            <ss:Data ss:type="String">@row.Core</Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
            <ss:Data ss:type="String">@row.BuyerSource</Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
            <ss:Data ss:type="String">@row.BuyerTwelveMonthSales</Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
            <ss:Data ss:type="String">@row.BuyerMonthsNoSale</Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
            <ss:Data ss:type="String">@row.BuyerQOH</Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
            <ss:Data ss:type="String">@row.BuyerQOO</Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
            <ss:Data ss:type="String">@row.SellerQtyAvail</Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
            <ss:Data ss:type="String">@row.QtyReq</Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
            <ss:Data ss:type="String">@row.BuyerAvgMonthSupply</Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
            <ss:Data ss:type="String">@row.BuyerStockingStatus</Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
            <ss:Data ss:type="String">@row.BuyerBin</Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
            <ss:Data ss:type="String">@row.BuyerLastSale</Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
            <ss:Data ss:type="String">@row.BuyerLastReceived</Data>
        </ss:Cell>
        <ss:Cell>
            <ss:Data ss:type="String">@row.PackageQty</Data>
        </ss:Cell>
    </ss:Row>
}
  </ss:Table>
</ss:Worksheet>
</ss:Workbook>
```

Comment: Are you trying to display raw xml in a View?

Comment: No by specifying content type: "application/vnd.ms-excel", browser will open it as excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution looks like it was just a typo, in cell section of the foreach loop:

```
<ss:Data ss:type="String">@row.QtyReq</Data>
```

ss:type should start with capital letter:

```
<ss:Data ss:Type="String">@row.QtyReq</Data>
```

It works fine now.